# How to clear all the content from the Slate editor with slate-yjs?

Tags: javascript, slate, yjs

I am using `@slate-yjs/core` with `@slate-yjs/react` with my Slate editor for collaborative editing.

In some of the situations, I need to clean up entire document and reload with new content. As far as I know, no such API exists such that I can simply recreate/reset the underlying Y.js document.

So, is there any way to achieve this with Slate and Y.js?